# PHP - Convert latitude and longitude to x and y cordinate, without using any library

Tags: php, google-maps, dictionary, geolocation, latitude-longitude

This question have been asked many times but i want the answer which i can use in a php application.

The closest answer i found was this

```
int x =  (int) ((MAP_WIDTH/360.0) * (180 + lon));
int y =  (int) ((MAP_HEIGHT/180.0) * (90 - lat));
```

I don't need to show the map or something. I just need to calculate it.

What should be the MAP_WIDTH and MAP_HEIGTH if i use the above formula ?

Comment: *What* do you want to achieve? The earth does not have "natural" `x` and `y` coordinates. X and Y are usually used in *projected maps*, but you just said you don't want a map...

Comment: Can anyone please explain the reason of marking negative ?

Comment: Because I have a program that traverse the map using x,y cordinates and then tells the nearby cities.

Comment: Well, if you compute Euclidean distance on `x`, `y` of an arbitrary projection, your results will be incorrect...

Comment: thanks for the answer @Anony-Mousse. So now i'll need to find nearby cities using lat long then.

Comment: The reason for downvoting is that you apparently did not bother to search for "latitude longitude distance" or "geographical distance" or "earth distance" or read up on map projections. Your question is assuming the world is a 2D rectangle, while everybody should know it is approximately a sphere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `x` and `y` coordinates for the earth. At most, you could compute `x`, `y` and `z`. Note that Euclidean distance then would travel through the earth surface.

It should also be pretty obvious that any `x-y` based system will produce completely inaccurate results close to the poles and close to the date line...

Keep the data as it is - in latitude, longitude (and height, if available) - and instead of computing Euclidean distance, use the great circle distance. Unless you have detailed information about the actual shape of the earth, the common great circle approximation with a sphere is the best you can do. And actually quite easy to use.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance